# How do I make a pattern of holes going through a mesh ? I'm working on a chair and I'm new to Blender

Tags: modeling

A pattern of hollow holes on the surface of the chair going through it[image]

Bottom of the chair[image]

Reference photo[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65395/repetitive-carvings-holes-around-a-sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210786/modeling-hexagon-pinhole-lens-for-3d-printing/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58811/how-to-create-a-circular-shaped-grid-similar-to-a-manhole-cover https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/creating-a-truck-exhaust-mesh

Comment: create a plane, subdivide once, delete the inner vertex, extrude and scale inwards, right click > LoopTools > Circle, extrude down to give thickness, delete the side faces, array on X and Y, enable the Merge option of the arrays, give it a Subdivision Surface modifier