# How to make holes in chair like in this picture?

Tags: modeling, retopology

Does anyone know how to properly make this holes in chair ? Without boolean. With good retopology.
[image]

Comment: It looks like this is a good starting point: [Modeling hexagon pinhole lens for 3D printing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/210786/60486) (subdivided hexagons become circles)

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the shape of the chair then you could make the holes separate and use shrink-wrap to project them onto it. Then duplicate the chair chair surface and manually cut a whole in it to insert the hole grid.
As for good topology, maybe something like this?
[image]